I cannot use Predict_proba for LinearSVC modek
I am new in building predictive models. I am trying to use predict_proba with CalibratedClassifierCV but it show this error. I have try to adjust the parameters but it does not work either
base_svm = LinearSVC(penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', dual=True, tol=0.0001, C=1.0, multi_class='ovr', fit_intercept=True,                       intercept_scaling=1, class_weight=None, verbose=0, random_state=123451, max_iter=10000)

svm = LinearSVC()
model = CalibratedClassifierCV(base_svm)

def get_cv_results(X, y, models):
    cv_results = {m:{'coef':[], 'train accuracy':[], 'train AUC':[], 'confusion matrix':[], \
                     'test accuracy':[], 'test AUC':[], 'ROC curve':[]} for m in models}
    seeds = [1,2,3,4,5,21,22,23,24,25,51,52,53,54,55,91,92,93,94,95] # 20 seeds
    
    for seed in seeds:
        skfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = seed) 
        for train_index, val_index in skfold.split(X, y):
            X_train_cv = X.iloc[train_index, :]
            y_train_cv = y.iloc[train_index]

            X_val = X.iloc[val_index, :]
            y_val = y.iloc[val_index]

            for m in cv_results: 
                model = models[m] 
                model.fit(X_train_cv, y_train_cv)

                y_fitted = model.predict_proba(X_train_cv)[:, 1]
                y_fitted_class = model.predict(X_train_cv)

                y_predict = model.predict_proba(X_val)[:, 1]
                y_predict_class = model.predict(X_val)

AttributeError: 'LinearSVC' object has no attribute 'predict_proba'

